# How to copy a type from a predefined assembly to a dynamic AssemblyBuilder

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, reflection.emit

I am working on a framework that has some pre-written c# code which ends up in a DLL. I then have another build step in which I want to use Reflection.Emit to generate the rest of the code in the framework.

Using Reflection.Emit, can I copy everything from the original DLL into the new DLL?

Answer (score -1):

No, I don't think you can use Reflection.Emit for that kind of manipulation. You might be able to generate a DLL that contains only the new code and then use something like ILMerge to merge the two DLLs into one.

Another option would be to use Mono.Cecil, which can add new types to an existing assembly directly.

Comment: @downvoter Care to comment what you think is wrong about this answer?